# Serialize a string with Serde without adding double quotes

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I am trying to serialize an enum into two consecutive csv fields.
The first field is a fixed string that depends on the enum variant, the second field is the value in the enum variant, with an extra "Hz" suffix. This is a separate enum type in my code but simplified here as a String.

I have generating Display with the expected format, then using SerializeDisplay. This works however it adds double quotes to the csv field, which I do not want.

How can I serialize a string without serde adding double quotes?

```rust
#[derive(SerializeDisplay)]
pub enum Tone {
    Up(String),
    Off,
}

impl Display for Tone {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Tone::Up(s) => write!(f, "TONE,{}Hz", s),
            Tone::Off => write!(f, "OFF,87.5Hz"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
        let tone = Tone::Up("hi".to_string());
        let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
            .has_headers(false)
            .from_writer(vec![]);
        wtr.serialize(tone).unwrap();
        let csv = String::from_utf8(wtr.into_inner().unwrap()).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(csv, "TONE,hiHz\n");
}
```

This results in

```rust
assertion `left == right` failed
  left: "\"TONE,hiHz\"\n"
 right: "TONE,hiHz\n"
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cabc50b35ce05a8df18e6b4ed0e5b83)

Comment: I can also implement Serialize directly with something like:
`let value = format!("TONE,{}Hz", ctcss);
serializer.serialize_str(&value)`
but the result is the same

Comment: The `,` in your string **must** be escaped, else it's a field separator.

Comment: @cafce25, thanks but yes I want it to become a field separator

Comment: Then you should serialize your 2 values *separately*, not as a single string.

Comment: @calman then you need to serialise as two separate fields, using the serialise trait.

Comment: Oh I see, the comma IS what is causing the double quotes to appear, as serde wants to escape it...  I will research how use the Serialize trait to have two fields. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cafce25 and @user1937198 for pointing that the comma I am using to serialize the variant to two csv fields is escaped by serde, and this is what is causing the extra double quotes.
To fix this I need to serialize the variant as two fields, by implementing Serialize on the outer struct (not displayed in the original question:

```rust
impl Serialize for DrMemory {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("DrMemory", 17)?;
        ...
        match &self.tone {
            Tone::Up(ctcss) => {
                state.serialize_field("TONE", "TONE")?;
                state.serialize_field("Repeater Tone", &format!("{}Hz", ctcss))?;
            }
            ...
            }
        }
        ...
        state.end()
    }
}
```